# Finding Value Based On Another Value and Range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So I am having a problem that I am not sure how to solve.

I have a data set in Excel that will be dynamically edited by a user, however the data will be of specific natures; I'm including a screenshot for reference. Referencing the included screenshot, I need a formula in cell H4 that will do the following: If cell G4 is not empty, look at cell B4 in the "Destination" column and see what the value in that cell is, then look in the entire "Destination" range for the same value and if found, look in the "Totes" column in the same row and see if the integer is lower than 500. If it is, look at the "Pallet Locations" column and find the value in the cell that is on the same row, then display that value in cell H4.

Hopefully that makes sense. I'm not really sure what formula to use for this kind of thing or if it is even feasible to do so, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way. Put this formula in cell `H4` in your above file.

`=IFERROR(IF(MIN(IF(B4:B11=IF(G4<>"",B4,""),E4:E11))<500,INDEX(A4:A11,MATCH(MIN(IF(B4:B11=IF(G4<>"",B4,""),E4:E11)),E4:E11,0)),""),"")`

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of normal <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

**Explanation**

> If cell G4 is not empty, look at cell B4 in the "Destination" column and see what the value in that cell is

```
IF(G4<>"",B4,"")
```

> then look in the entire "Destination" range for the same value and if found, look in the "Totes" column in the same row and see if the integer is lower than 500.

For this you need to find the minimum value for N1 in totes column. For that the formula is

```
MIN(IF(B4:B11="N1",E4:E11))
```

Lastly if you need to return the value which in the left column, you can use this

```
INDEX(A4:A11,MATCH("498",E4:E11)),E4:E11,0))
```

Now simply combine all the above formulas.

Comment: Both solutions work perfectly, though for simplicity's sake, I prefer your formula, it works fantastically well. Thank you!

Comment: Also, what does Use Ctrl + Shift + Enter do instead of just pressing Enter?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d

Comment: Ah, I see. So essentially super formulas. I've never had to use that before so I was unaware that was even a thing. Thanks again for your help, it's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in H4 and fill down.

```
=IF(G4<>TEXT(,), IFERROR(IF(INDEX(E:E, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(4:$11)/(B4:B$11=B4), 2))<500, INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(4:$11)/(B4:B$11=B4), 2)), TEXT(,)), TEXT(,)), TEXT(,))
```

[image]

Comment: Both solutions work perfectly, though for simplicity's sake, I prefer the Siddharth's formula. Thank you very much.